# image display error with lines displaying

Tags: html

![enter image description here][1]i have a problem. The image i put into the background is divided into four part. Header, body1,body2 and footer. My problenm is when body1 and body2 join together there is a line in the image. This also apply the same to body2 when i put a repeat, the line is there at the bottom. The problem is when one image in a div display then another image after that a line appear between them
This is my code:

```
<div id="header" 
        style="background-image:url('Graphic/banner.png'); height: 84px;">    
    </div>
    <div id="Body1" 
        style="background-image:url('Graphic/topper.png'); height: 364px;" >    
    </div>
    <div id="Body2" 
        style="background-image:url('Graphic/body.png'); height: 364px;">    
    </div>
    <div id="Footer" 
        style="background-image:url('Graphic/footer.png'); height: 82px;">    
    </div>
```

Any idea how to make the line disapear?

Comment: check for margins/paddings on the div

Comment: format your question first... we cant get anything

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: the line is still there. My question is when i put two image on the background of the website, a line appear between them. How do i make the line disappear?

Comment: look the site jsfiddle.com you can make your issue's example here or put a screenshot of your issue or link  your webpage to us. If you describe like this you cant get any answer here...

Answer (score 0):

Try This: here i have no spaces between the div's, make sure that there are no 
white spaces on your images.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" 
        style="background-image:url('#'); background-color: #EBC64D; height: 84px;">    
    </div>
<div id="container">    
    <div id="Body1" 
        style="background-image:url('#'); background-color: #07ED5F; height: 364px;" >    
    </div>

    <div id="Body2" 
        style="background-image:url('#'); background-color: #2E16A8; height: 364px;">    
    </div>
</div>  
    <div id="Footer" 
        style="background-image:url('#'); background-color: #E01B6A; height: 82px;">    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My problem occur when i try to put the div into tables. between each rows there is a line appear there

Comment: Check the properties of your table because it may be the border of the table making the lines.